# How can I encrypt the home directory after installing for Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, encryption

I already installed Ubuntu 22.04 and I need to encrypt the home directory or to encrypt the whole hard disk, what is the best way to do that? can I do the full disk encryption during the upgrading to 22.10 ?

Comment: "what is the best way to do that?" whatever method you are comfortable with. As long as you have backups that you know how to restore you can mess up all you want as you can then always restore a backup. You could also backup and re-install using encryption if you are unsure how to do this.

Comment: Ubuntu no longer offers *directory* or *partition* encryption (*by default at install*) as it was less secure than full-disk encryption, but what do you consider *best*??  That's a very *subjective* term & the *best* encryption with regards security is done prior to installation (ie. full-disk).

Comment: can I do the full disk encryption during the upgrading to 22.10 ?

Comment: Full disk encryption is offered during installation (*encryption options vary on product & ISO too*), a *release-upgrade* is not a new install but occurs on an existing install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What disadvantages are there to encrypting an entire hard drive or a home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409942/what-disadvantages-are-there-to-encrypting-an-entire-hard-drive-or-a-home-direct)

Answer (score 0):

The "best way" in many cases is subjective. What is best for one user may not be best for another. For general users, the "best" way  probably is is to make sure the backup of your data is up to date, then reinstall Ubuntu making sure the respective drives are encrypted.

If you are highly skilled in Linux, there may be other ways. Ubuntu offers partition based encryption. If you want to encrypt only a home directory that is on the system partition, you will need to use other methods.

Whatever you try, the duty of making sure your backup is up to date will not be changed.